# Consider that to mean 'believe that'

Tags: meaning, word-choice

The European audit authority "the Court" systematically presents its findings/opinions with sentences that begin: 'the Court considers that....' This sounds like a gallicism to me. Can we use 'consider that' in this way? If so, how does it differ from 'believes','thinks', 'finds' or 'feels'?

e.g. *'The Court considers that the information system at present available to the Commission does not effectively serve the Commission’s needs.'
'The Court considers that competitive tendering would have been feasible for contracts for management services and audit'.*

Comment: Seems perfectly standard a use of *consider* to me.

Comment: "Considers" rather than being synonymous here with 'believes','thinks', or 'feels' is better understood as "concluded", or "decided", or as you mentioned, 'finds'.

Comment: @LittleEva The clue is in the *that*. If I say *On Friday evenings I consider what to do at the week-end* it clearly means that I *think about* what to do. But if I say *I consider that the man is a fool*, I am expressing an opinion. The *that* is not essential. I could have said *I consider him to be a fool*. *Consider* does have these two senses.

Comment: @WS2 - ya'll finally awake over there?

Comment: @LittleEva Up and doing while you were still tucked up in bed this morning.

Comment: @WS2 but I haven't been to bed in ages! I always sleep with one eye open anyway. Don't wanna miss anything good!

Comment: Thanks WS2. Curiously I am associated with both Norfolk and Berkshire too. I think you are right. Perhaps it is just the constant repetition of this expression that bothers me (never 'the court believes that' or 'the court thinks that' or 'the Court feels that'. I wonder what it thinks that it is adding by insisting on the word 'consider'. Maybe I should ask it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two [definitions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/consider) of *consider* that appear be relevant.

> Regard (someone or something) as having a specified quality: *I consider him irresponsible.*
>
> Believe; think: *I don’t consider that I’m to blame.*

There seems to be a bit of both senses in your examples. They express the court's beliefs, and those beliefs are about whether the information system has the quality of being effective, and whether competitive tendering has the quality of being feasible.

Since these "qualities" are extremely abstract, I think the intended sense is as a synonym for "believe".

Answer (score 0):

As in this case, **consider** carries a connotation of criteria. A court may **consider** a case or decline to hear it based on the strength of what has relevant legal standing. When a court **considers** an appeal it does not mean the court believes the appellant's argument.